# I think ive setup vscode the wrong way or not able to find out a few root reasons for a few errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling

[image]

why is this error there in the terminal?

i was trying to run a simple file after saving it yet it wasnt able to locate the file in the directory as mentioned, hence was giving the following error.

Comment: You have a typo on line 2, remove the `:` and the code will work

Comment: Close the current terminal and rerun the code. Your current terminal has python interactive open.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix this is to remove `:` at the end of second line. It is a **typo** which kind of **destroys** rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current terminal, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and press Enter to exit the current python interactive mode.

When your terminal looks like this you can use the play button to run the code.

[image]

When your terminal looks like this, it means that you have opened the python interactive terminal, where you can directly type the code and run it, but you cannot run the command.

[image]

By the way, as others have said there is a bug in your code, you need to remove the semicolon at the end of the second line.